# ARCore+Unity3D: How to make a scene oriented to north?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gps, arcore

I've been playing around with ARCore in Unity.

What I want to achieve is spawning objects according to input GPS coordinates and current GPS position (e.g. the object should be spawned at x.xxxxx, y.yyyyy coordinates which translate to world coordinates in Unity).

I figured out that in order to place objects correctly I need to somehow maintain the north orientation.

How can it be possible with ARCore? In ARKit the scene is created so that one of the axis is heading north (according to compass reading at the scene creation moment). This is not the case with ARCore.

Is there a workaround for ARCore?

Comment: Is there any way you can show us what you have tried ?

Comment: And can you share an image of your scene ?

Comment: I am currently trying to solve the same problem. Did you manage to orient the whole scene?

Comment: I didn't. I tried many things but I would still get weird results. I guess the precision of the device's in-built compass in not enough to spawn objects in the right place.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer in Unity Docs:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Compass-magneticHeading.html

```
function Update () {
       // Orient an object to point to magnetic north.
       transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, -Input.compass.magneticHeading, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for that but I was considering the orientation of the whole 3D scene.. So that when you spawn an object at e.g. (0, 0, 1) it will be spawned directly in the geographical north.